# JavaScript delete <li> already existed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question on how to delete specific already made `<li>` with Javascript.

```js
var Dodaja = document.getElementById('dodaj');
var Tekst = document.getElementById('tekst');
var Lista = document.getElementById('todo');
Dodaja.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var oNovaLista = document.createElement('li');
  oNovaLista.innerHTML = Tekst.value;
  Lista.appendChild(oNovaLista);
  oNovaLista.addEventListener("click", function() {
    Lista.removeChild(oNovaLista);
  })
});
```

```html
<ul id="todo">
  <li>To do 1</li>
  <li>To do 2</li>
  <li>To do 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="input">
  <input type="text" id="tekst">
  <button id="dodaj">Dodaj</button>
</div>
```

With this code I can not delete already existing `<li>` from HTML ('To do 1', 'To do 2', 'To do 3')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation instead - add a listener to the parent `#todo`, and watch for clicks on child `<li>`s:

```js
var Dodaja = document.getElementById('dodaj');
var Tekst = document.getElementById('tekst');
var Lista = document.getElementById('todo');
Dodaja.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var oNovaLista = document.createElement('li');
  oNovaLista.innerHTML = Tekst.value;
  Lista.appendChild(oNovaLista);
});

Lista.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('li')) {
    e.target.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="todo">
  <li>To do 1</li>
  <li>To do 2</li>
  <li>To do 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="input">
  <input type="text" id="tekst">
  <button id="dodaj">Dodaj</button>
</div>
```

You could also add a listener separately to both the elements that exist on pageload and the elements that get added dynamically, but it's uglier:

```js
var Dodaja = document.getElementById('dodaj');
var Tekst = document.getElementById('tekst');
var Lista = document.getElementById('todo');
Dodaja.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var oNovaLista = document.createElement('li');
  oNovaLista.innerHTML = Tekst.value;
  Lista.appendChild(oNovaLista);
  oNovaLista.addEventListener("click", function() {
    Lista.removeChild(oNovaLista);
  })
});
for (const li of document.querySelectorAll('#todo li')) {
  li.addEventListener("click", function() {
    Lista.removeChild(li);
  })
}
```

```html
<ul id="todo">
  <li>To do 1</li>
  <li>To do 2</li>
  <li>To do 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="input">
  <input type="text" id="tekst">
  <button id="dodaj">Dodaj</button>
</div>
```